Can a Silent Hallcreeper copy another Silent Hallcreeper to refresh its one-use abilities?
If I have two Silent Hallcreepers A and B out, and A has used has already used its first and second abilities, can it use its final ability to copy the B Hallcreeper, and essentially refresh those abilities by being treated as a new copy?

Yes, using one copy of Silent Hallcreeper copy another will "reset" the abilities.
When a creature becomes a copy of another, all of its original characteristics are overwritten. (except when the ability says otherwise)
So while it gets a new ability with the exact same text, it has no connection to the previous one.
It's also worth noting that it will not copy the modes already chosen by the other Silent Hallcreeper, as modes chosen aren't a copiable value.

707.2 ... The copiable values are the values derived from the text printed on the object (that text being name, mana cost, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, power, toughness, and/or loyalty), as modified by other copy effects, by its face-down status, and by “as . . . enters” and “as . . . is turned face up” abilities that set power and toughness (and may also set additional characteristics). Other effects (including type-changing and text-changing effects), status, counters, and stickers are not copied.


Since it's legally a new copy and not the original card, can you repeat indefinitely to accumulate counters?

@CristobolPolychronopolis - Don't you need to deal attack damage again somehow?

Of course, you'd have one chance per turn, but after the second you'd have 2 5/5 unblockables, and if that's not good enough, they'll be 7/7 on the third.

Yes, you can theoretically continue to accumulate an unlimited number of counters, but you need 2 combat steps per growth cycle.
You could potentially use Combat Celebrant, Hellkite Charger, or Scourge of the Throne to generate additional combat steps on the same turn if needed.

"It's also worth noting that it will not copy the modes already chosen by the other Silent Hallcreeper, as modes chosen aren't a copiable value." Even if they were, the ability refers to the modes chosen by that ability. So if [mtg:Marvin, Murderous Mimic] didn't specify "activated abilities", and you had two Hallcreepers, then Marvin would have two copies of the ability, and each time one of the copies of the abilities triggered, you could choose any mode that you haven't chosen for that copy, regardless of whether you've chosen it for another copy.
